# Exception Handling Unreachable code

Tags: java, exception

Following is my code, when I am commenting statement-2 then it complies fines but when I uncomment it gives Compile Time Error `"Unreachable Code"`.

I understand why I am getting error after uncommenting it, but my question is even if I comment it still the `bad()` is unreachable as I am `throwing` an exception is catch then why it is not giving error for it ?

```
class Varr 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  { 
    System.out.println("Main");
    try {
      good();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Main catch");
      //**Statement 1**    
      throw new RuntimeException("RE");
    } finally {
      System.out.println("Main Finally");
      //  **Statement 2**    
      throw new RuntimeException("RE2");
    }
    bad();
  }
}
```

Comment: `bad()` is not unreachable, if you comment-out `Statement 2`. I think you have a misconception about `finally`. And one remark: You should neither return nor throw something in a `finally`-block. This can lead to well-defined, but hard to understand behaviour. In your example, you will always throw a `"RE2"`-Exception since `finally` is always executed and beats everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> but my question is even if i comment it still the bad() is
>   unreachable as i am throwing an exception is catch then why it is not
>   giving error for it ?

Because the execution  will not necessary enter in the `catch` statement.
Suppose that `good()` doesn't thrown any exception, so you don't enter  in the `catch` and therefore `bad()` is then executed :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{   
    System.out.println("Main");
    try {
        good(); // doesn't throw an exception
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        System.out.println("Main catch");
        throw new RuntimeException("RE");
    }
    bad(); // execution goes from good() to here
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i understood it.
Also if i throw an exception in try block which will ensure that catch block executes, keeping the catch block as it is and removing the finally block then also bad() becomes unreachable